# Getting 127.0.0.1 when using HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>()?.RemoteIpAddress

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using asp.net core with mvc. I am trying to get the IP address using the below code.

```
var ipAddress = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>()?.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
```

Its always returning ::1 which means 127.0.0.1 on my local machine which is fine. But now I have hosted it on azure cloud only for testing using my testing azure account and it is still giving me 127.0.0.1.

What I am doing wrong?

**project.json**

```
    {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "author": [ "Musaab Mushtaq", "Programmer" ],
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "DeveloperForce.Force": "1.3.0",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc2-final",
    "IntegraPay.Domain": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8",
        "net45"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config",
      "config.json",
      "Views"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
  public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(option => { option.ForwardedHeaders = Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.ForwardedHeaders.XForward‌​edFor; });
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSingleton(provider => Configuration);
            services.AddTransient<IRegistrationRepository, ServiceUtilities>();
            services.AddTransient<IClientServiceConnector, ClientServiceValidation>();
        }

        private IClientServiceConnector ForceClientService { get;set; }
        private IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment enviroment)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (enviroment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Registration/Error");
            }

            app.UseRuntimeInfoPage("/Info");
            app.UseFileServer();
            ConfigureRestAuthenticationSetting(enviroment);
            app.UseMvc(ConfigureRoutes);
            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        }

        private void ConfigureRestAuthenticationSetting(IHostingEnvironment enviroment)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(enviroment.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("config.json");
            Configuration = config.Build();
        }

        private void ConfigureRoutes(IRouteBuilder routeBuilder)
        {
            routeBuilder.MapRoute("Default", "{controller=Registration}/{action=Index}/{formId?}");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Can't you people stop using MVC6? It's not MVC6 anymore,  because it creates confusion!! https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/01/19/asp-net-5-is-dead-introducing-asp-net-core-1-0-and-net-core-1-0/, the MVC package version number is 1.0.0, **not** 6.0.0!

Comment: In most real-life scenarios over the internet, `RemoteIpAddress` is entirely useless. Are you sure that in your case, it has any significance? Many users have dynamic IP addresses, many users *share* the same IP address at the same time, many users use a proxy, and that's still on the client side. On the server side, you have load balancers, reverse proxies, port forwarding... What are you trying to use the IP address for?

Comment: I am trying to get the country from where the user is accessing the website.

Answer (score 5):

This happen because of reverse proxy. With ASP.net core IIS send request to Kestrel server to processing and as MVC 6 ( ASP.net core) receive request after that this issue will come as some header information will not get forwarded.

Following thing will solve your problem.

**In your Startup.cs file.**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
      loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
      loggerFactory.AddDebug();
      app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions() { ForwardedHeaders = Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.ForwardedHeaders.All }); // This must be first line. ( Before other middleware get configured)
      // your other code
    }
```

**Update 1**
1. Don't use Service.Configure and app.UseForwardedHeaders together. ( I have tried to use both option together and it ended up as 127.0.0.1). 
2. I have use only app.UseForwardedHeaders and it works fine.

My Minimal Configuration File. ( Startup.cs)

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddMvc();
        //services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(option => { option.ForwardedHeaders = Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.ForwardedHeaders.All; });  // This option should not be used. it gives me 127.0.0.1 if I have used this option.
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions() { ForwardedHeaders = Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.ForwardedHeaders.All });
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

Later I tried with Service.Configure and It works. In that case I have only use Service.Configure and avoid using app.UseForwardedHeaders.

In that case my Startup.cs file like this.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddMvc();
        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(option => { option.ForwardedHeaders = Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.ForwardedHeaders.XForward‌​edFor; });  
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);
        //app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions() { ForwardedHeaders = Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.ForwardedHeaders.All });
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: I amtrying to do the other way.  In my ConfigureServices method I am having putting the below code,  services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(option =>
            {
                option.ForwardedHeaders = Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor;
            }); But unfortunately I am getting some ambiguous error.

Comment: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure<TOptions>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Action<TOptions>)' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure<TOptions>(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Action<TOptions>)'

Comment: It seems that you have two version of same dll or something. If it is only problem on release version then please delete everything on release folder and try to republish it.

Comment: I Have tried your solution. But still I am getting the same ip address.

Comment: I have tried your updated solution. But I cannot use Configure method it is throwing same ambiguous error. I have checked my project.json file there are no duplicate references.

Comment: You can any of one update. Update 1 is without service configure method

Comment: Update 1 Doesnot work for me. It turn same 127.0.0.1

Comment: If possible I have to to see project.json and startup.cs. did it work local network ? I was not able to test on azure but local network it works fine

Comment: I have Updated my question. Locally It gives me 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I suggest that you should use rtm not rc1 which mention in many of your dll reference

Comment: I am using rc2-final. what is rtm?

Comment: There is final release 1.0.0. In that reference look like  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0". https://github.com/aspnet/cli-samples/blob/master/HelloMvcApi/project.json

Comment: Can you please come on chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121883/discussion-between-dotnetstep-and-maxspan).

Answer (score -1):

This works for me when deploying on cloud:

```
var forwardOpts = new ForwardedHeadersOptions { ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All };
forwardOpts.KnownNetworks.Clear();
forwardOpts.KnownProxies.Clear();
app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardOpts);
```